# Extending MIPS one-cycle data path to implement movcn

Tags: mips, hardware, processor

I have trouble implementing the movcn instruction in MIPS. ([MIPS One-Cycle Datapath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh5tG.png))

Here is how the instruction is defined:

R[rd] = R[rs] if R[rt] < 0

I am not sure what to use to compare if R[rt] < 0. Should I add a comparator in the path?

Answer (score 0):

I think we're in the same UdeM class! Movcn isn't native to MIPS.

You already have a comparator in the datapath; the ALU. Consider that your read data 2 output from the Register File (RD2) should be changed to zero before being inputted into the ALU, if a certain signal is recieved indicating that the instruction is movcn.

I'm not gonna say anything else, but hopefully this helps you out enough to set you on the right track. Good luck with the homework, and godspeed.